# Is it possible to register the same class / interface multiple times in Spring4D?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I'm currently playing around with the Spring4D framework and think it's pretty cool.  I'm trying to achieve the following

```
  GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TPerson>.Implements<IPerson>('Normal');
  GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TPerson>.Implements<IPerson>('TestData').DelegateTo(
    function: TPerson
    begin
      result := TPerson.Create;
      result.SetFirstName('Bob');
      result.SetSurname('Smith');
    end
  );
```

With TPerson/IPerson having the obvious definitions. But regardless if I try

```
  Person := ServiceLocator.GetService<IPerson>('Normal');
```

or

```
  Person := ServiceLocator.GetService<IPerson>('TestData');
```

I always get Bob, is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Works fine with me.  Are you using the latest source? RegisterComponent is deprecated now and you should use RegisterType instead, but using both worked ok for me too.  There is something else happening in your code at a guess.

Comment: Please make sure to use the latest version from the trunk. This bug should not exist.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Would love to checkout the latest version, but I'm behind a firewall and I've been unable to work out the correct proxy settings for svn, I'll try again when at home tonight

Comment: @Jason I've stripped it back as far as I can with another example and still have the same issue.  I'm using Spring4D_V1.0.3.12.zip.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the latest version of Spring4D